# How to set a control in XAML visible if another control is visible on the same page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a card in Xamarin Forms that I want to be visible only if a button is visible as well. For some reason the same IsVisible attribute for the button isn't working for the card, so is there a way for me to say if the button is visible, let the card be visible?

```
<cor:BindableToolbarItem x:Name="Inside"
            Command="{Binding InsideCommand}"
            IsVisible="{Binding SelectedReading.Inside, Converter={StaticResource valueIsNotNull}}"
            Icon="hi.png"
            Order="Primary" />
```

That's the button on the toolbar:

```
<controls:InsideCard 
              BindingContext="{x:Reference Inside}"
              IsVisible="{Binding SelectedReading.Inside, Converter={StaticResource valueIsNotNull}}">
            </controls:InsideCard>
```

As you can see the IsVisible is the same for both, but it isn't working, so I tried referencing the button inside the card but it doesn't work obviously. How can I do it properly?

Comment: Could you provide more information about `controls:InsideCard ` and `cor:BindableToolbarItem`? You used nuget packages plugin or custom controls, If you do not porivde this information, we cannot re-produce your issue.

Comment: Oh sorry.. the files themselves are way to big to post here, hundreds of lines of code, but they're basically the same as the BaseCard and MenuItem. Nothing special in there, so I don't think they should have anything to with this simple question, of how and if it's possible to use the IsVisible property of one control in another control in the same xaml file?

Comment: When you set BindingContext to `{x:Reference Inside}`. Binding the `IsVisible` property is what you need not the `SelectedReading.Inside`, if the Binding Context is correctly set. Please try this and check...   . Are the break points in converters hitting?

Comment: Since BindingContext is set to Inside, it is trying to find `SelectedReading` object in `Inside` object... set the binding context properly and everything will work fine. If you need more help, provide the entire xaml...

Comment: @Nikhileshwar Is this what you mean: `<controls:InsideCard
              BindingContext="{x:Reference Inside}"
              IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource valueIsNotNull}}" />`

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant. Did it work?

Comment: Just tried it and it did work! I just had to remove the Converter part of the IsVisible! Thanks so much, if you make an answer I can mark is as correct for you if you'd like @Nikhileshwar

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have added an answer. I have also mentioned other ways of doing this please do have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindingContext` is set to the `Inside` element hence the `SelectedReading.Inside` property will not be available in the `Inside` object. Hence the binding won't work. Bind the `IsVisible` property of `Inside`.

```cs
<controls:InsideCard BindingContext="{x:Reference Inside}" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
```

Or set the source of binding to `{x:Reference Inside}` in Binding markup itself.

```cs
<controls:InsideCard IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference Inside}}"/>
```

**Just to add:**

Moreover binding same property to two different Views should work too (If you are setting it in ViewModel). Or also setting Mode as TwoWay for `Inside` element. For both the cases you must have implemented the NotifyPropertyChanged for the binded property of ViewModel.

```cs
    <Label
        x:Name="label1"
        IsVisible="{Binding ViewVisiblity}"
        Text="Hi there"/>
    <Label
        x:Name="label2"
        Text="Hi there2"
        IsVisible="{Binding ViewVisiblity, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```